# How do i set action name for axios request (in react app)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have an app which executes several requests with `axios` lib. Requests looks like this:

```
export const actionGetUser = token => {
    let currentToken = token ? token : window.localStorage.token;
    prodLog('actionGetUser', { currentToken })

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
    ...
```

I can log sending data (current token here) using `axios.interceptors`, but how do i log an action name (actionGetUser here) without using my custom function `prodLog`?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by logging. Do you want the actual request that is going out to somehow contain the action name?

Comment: no, i just want to print in console name of the action which executes request, but i dont want to put in each request a string like ```prodLog('actionGetUser', { currentToken })``` or ```console.log()```. my be there are any way to specify a property for certain request?

Comment: So, i'm understanding that you have thunk action creators in which you're making multiple requests with axios. You want to console.log which action creator is responsible for making actual http requests. Afaik this is not possible without putting that logging code in the action creator yourself. Keep in mind that the thunk actions don't have the type property, since they're functions dispatching other actions.